# How to do a basic GraphQL query to Shopify with Ruby

Tags: ruby, graphql, shopify, sinatra, shopify-app

I'm trying to do a basic GraphQL query to a Shopify store with Sinatra. Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I looked at their API to do this:

```
require 'shopify_api'
require 'sinatra'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    shop  = 'xxxx.myshopify.com'
    token = 'shpat_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(domain: shop, token: token, api_version: "2021-04")
    ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
    
    ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.initialize_clients
    client = ShopifyAPI::GraphQL.client

    SHOP_NAME_QUERY = client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
      {
        shop {
          name
        }
      }
    GRAPHQL

    result = client.query(SHOP_NAME_QUERY)
    result.data.shop.name
  end
end
```

Which gives this error but I don't want to use Rake or Rails. Is it possible to do a GraphQL query to Shopify with Ruby?

```
ShopifyAPI::GraphQL::InvalidClient at /
Client for API version 2021-04 does not exist because no schema file exists at `shopify_graphql_schemas/2021-04.json`. To dump the schema file, use the `rake shopify_api:graphql:dump` task
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you need to first dump the schema (see this link: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/v9/docs/graphql.md#dump-the-schema).

Then you create a `shopify_graphql_schemas` directory in the same root as your ruby script, and put the generated JSON there.

Like stated in the comments, this requires a `Rake` task, so you need to be using `Rails`.
If your project doesn't use Rails, you need to do a quick workaround.

You create a temporary barebones Rails project, then generate the dump using that project (you can delete the project when you're done with this).
It's a bit hacky, but it's the only thing I can see that would work.

Comment: I saw that but this requires a `Rake` task which I believe requires using Rails?

Comment: That's true. If your project isn't using Rails, then you have to do an additional manipulation. I've updated the answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

New link to schema dump
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/blob/v9/docs/graphql.md#dump-the-schema

You need to use something like this

```
rake shopify_api:graphql:dump SHOP_DOMAIN="SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com" ACCESS_TOKEN="SHOP_TOKEN" API_VERSION=2022-04
```

Old one doesn't work anymore

Comment: What if the rake task shopify_api:graphql:dump does not exist? Do you know how to get that task? Note: shopify_api + shopify_app gem newest versions are installed, at some point updating one of those gems removed that rake task :/

Comment: @Joe'sIdeas, sorry, i don't know
But as i see in my example word "task" not used

Again, Im not sure